# ASP.net MVC User Control - Grid plus Details view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have around 50+ tables in my database for which I need to generate a gridview and details view in a MVC website. Is there any pre-existing user control available in MVC? 
So that I can just feed the table name and it generates a page with Grid and details view?

Answer (score 0):

You can just create the model representing each database schema, fill the model from the data in those databases, and create a view off each of the databases. The views and controller won't be hard to create (Visual Studio does a pretty good job of auto-populating those), but you have to create the model first and connect each model to your databases. It'll be easier if any of your db schemas are the same.

The reason that there is not an 1-click solution to creating your models (which is what I believe you're asking) is that there is a *ton* of customization that you can do with any model, including what data you want (as SELECT * from DB might not always be what you want), how secure you want your model fields to be, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such pre-existing user control. You need to use the Grid widget like demonstrated [here](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/hierarchy.html).